# get EditText value in service

Tags: java, android, service, android-edittext

Currently I'm doing a task for my company, where I need to implement a password. This password is actually is a `Service`. Beforehand, I test my password, just use a simple android project (that project is `Activity`) and I can get done this, and then I use the same method to do in `Service` but `Service` cannot get the EditText value eventhough my EditText UI already filled with the value that I pressed on the keypad. Below is the code:

**PasswordView.java:**

```
import GetAsteriskForPassword;
import Log;
import InstanceManager;
import R;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PasswordView extends FrameLayout {

    private View mBaseView;
    private EditText mPassword;
    private TextView mPasswordTitle;
    private final String mActualPass = "027";


    public PasswordView() {
        super(InstanceManager.getService());
        init();
    }

    /**
     * initialize. called from constructor.
     */
    private void init() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

        mBaseView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_password, this, false);
        addView(mBaseView);
        Log.i("paswordView", "==== paswordView");

        mPasswordTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblPassword);
        mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);

        setPasswordParameter();
    }

    private void setPasswordParameter() {
        final Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromFile("LCFONT_LATIN");
        mPasswordTitle.setText("Input Password");
        mPasswordTitle.setTypeface(typeface);
        mPassword.setTransformationMethod(new GetAsteriskForPassword());
        mPassword.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL);
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        mPassword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Log.i("paswordView", "==== afterTextChanged");
                setTextValue(s);
            }

        });
    }

    private void setTextValue(final Editable s) {
        Log.i("paswordView", "==== setTextValue");
        if (s.length() < 3) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            if (mActualPass.equals(s.toString())) {
                MenuWindow.getInstance().open();
            }
            PasswordWindow.getInstance().close();
        }
    }
}
```

When I type in the EditText, the value is display in the UI, but function `afterTextChanged(Editable s)` just simply didn't run. The log didn't come out when I typed into the UI.

Anyone here know how to correct this?
Thank you!

Comment: Where calling `addListenerOnButton ` method?

Comment: oh my god. what a silly mistake!! i forgot to called that function. thank you for remind me. I add `addListenerOnButton()` at the `public PasswordView()`. now my code is working now. seriously what a silly mistake. thanks again!!!

Comment: should probably close this question as it poses no value to the community.